# Unspecified integers command-line

Tags: java, string, command-line, count

I am trying to write a program that passes an unspecified number of integers as command-line arguments to the main method and display:

- the total number of integers that the user entered
- and their total

Here is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
int number, sum = 0;
do {        
number = input.nextInt();
sum = sum + number;
++count;

}
while(number != 0);
        // Displays number count.
        System.out.println("You entered "  + count + " numbers");
        // Displays the total.
        System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
    }
}
```

I wanted to have a method to count the number of integers in a string, a for loop and next char and an integer count to keep track of it, and a method to add numbers but I'm not sure how to write it without getting compilation errors.

Comment: Which getting compilation errors ? You're using cli arguments, but a user iput AFTER the program has started

Answer (score 0):

Your program works well but doesn't use *cli argument** but rather *user input*.

The difference is that for

- the 1st argument are given before program start

  ```
  java myProgram arg1 arg2
  >> output
  ```
- in the 2nd case arguments are asked and read during program run

  ```
  java myProgram 
  >> Please give arg1:
  12
  >> Please give arg2:
  22
  >> output
  ```

---

So as your program does the *user input*, here's the code for cli argument:

```
int count = 0;
int number, sum = 0;
for (String arg : args) {
    number = Integer.parseInt(arg);
    sum = sum + number;
    ++count;
}
System.out.println("You entered " + count + " numbers");
System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
```